# gem install addressable -v 2.4.0, installed Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows, error installing bundle

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm a beginner trying to get started with Dashing - a Sinatra based framework that lets you build dashboards.

Ruby- trying to install bundle, get an error - Gem:: RemoteFetcher::FetchError SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read sever certficate B:certificate verify failed(https://rubygems.org/gems/addressable -2.4.00 gem) gem install addressable -v 2.4.0.
Error occurred which installing addressable (2.4.0) and Bundler cannot continue
Make sure that 'gem install addressabel -v 2.4.0 succeeds before bundling.

I've tried to find a solution but, haven't found any yet. If anyone knows how to resolve please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88, it might help you in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks Nabeel, I've tried this before posting my question. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling ruby. That seemed to have resolved the issue.